# Demonstrate $f(a,b)=2^a (2b+1)-1$ is surjective using induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I am trying to show that $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, where $f(a,b)=2^a (2b+1)-1$, is surjective using induction (possibly strong induction). In the case $n=0$, it is easy to see that $(0,0)$ does the trick.

Suppose there exist elements of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ which map to each $n\in\{0,1,\dots,k\}$, consider the case $k+1$.

All I have is:
$k+1=f(x,y)+1$ for some $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, but I do not know how to continue. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To show that the mapping is onto, it is the same as showing that all numbers $b\in \{1 , 2, 3, 4, \cdots\}$ can be written as $b = 2^k c$, where $k\ge 0$ and $c$ is odd.

Comment: I agree. I guess I would just like to demonstrate the induction in the form it is written for the sake of argument. I believe I need to find $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(p,q)=f(x,y)+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more convenient to show that every positive integer $n$ can be represented in the form $2^a(2b+1)$, where $a$ and $b$ are nonl-negative integers. We use strong induction. The result is clearly true for $n=1$. Let us suppose it is true for all $k\lt n$, and show it is true for $n$.

Perhaps $n$ is odd, say $2b+1$. Then we can take $a=0$.

Perhaps $n$ is even, say $n=2m$. By the induction hypothesis, there exist natural numbers  $a_1$ and $b$ such that $m=2^{a_1}(2b+1)$. Then $n=2^a(2b+1)$, where $a=a_1+1$.